# Unable to use a bot with the QnA (NodeJS) template

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-qna-maker

I just created a QnA Bot by using the following steps:

1. Create a bot using the "Question and Answer (NodeJS)" template.
2. Update "QnAKnowledgebaseId" and "QnASubscriptionKey" in "Application Settings".

However, it always shows "Waiting for bot to be ready" when I navigated to "Test in Web Chat": [image: waiting-for-bot-to-be-ready]

It works well if we choose "C# Basic" or "Node.js Basic".

Here is the error messages: [image: web-chat-recent-issues]

How can I make it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the npm modules failed to load. They load in the C# qna maker bot so you can either use the C# bot or you need to load the npm packages.

In order to load the npm packages, click on build (just above "test in web chat"), select the second menu item in the top blue bar (should be your app name), and select "Open Kudu console". You need to change directory to D:\home\site\wwwroot and run "npm install" from there. After that completes, give the web app a minute, then try again.